# Python: what is the operation that returns 6 for the expression (2 and 2*3)?

Tags: python

My first question is what is the more abstract question for the question: 'what is the operation that returns 6 for the expression  `(2 and 2*3)`? Please feel free to retitle my question appropriately.

My second question is what is it that is going on in python that returns 6 for `(2 and 2*3)`. There seems something elegant going on here, and I'd like to read up on this operation.

Comment: Assuming you understand the multiplication operator. The two other things you need to understand are [boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) and [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument.

As such, `2 and 2*3` means it first evaluates `bool(2)`, which evaluates to `True`, and then it evaluates `bool(2*3)` which evaluates to `True`. Therefore it'll return the last evaluated argument, which is `2*3` (`6`).

Answer (score 3):

First you have to read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and then you have to read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). :)

After that you will know that `and` is a boolean operator, that tries to convert it's first operand to boolean. So if you read the first thing you will see that `2` is converted to `True`.

The third thing you need to know is that the `and` operand will return it's first argument if it is converted to `False` and it's second argument if it evaluates to `True`.

So basically

```
z = x and y
```

Can be translated to:

```
if x:
    z = y
else:
    z = x
```

And now you understand everything. :)

`2` is evaluated to `True` and then `and` operator returns the value of it's second argument which is `6`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)
x and y : if x is false, then x, else y

Answer (score 1):

Applying lazy evaluation, python return for `a and b` a if a evaluates to False and b if a evaluates to True.

Hence 2 evaluates to True, `2 and 2*3` return `2*3` which equals 6.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's same as `2 and 6`.

How it works? `and` returns first element if it's considered False (`False`, `0`, `[]` ...) and return second otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with how Python evaluates the expression `x and y`. It returns `y` if `x` is `True`, and `x` if `x` if `False`.

So, in case of `2 and 2 * 3`, since `2` is evaluated to `True`, it would return the value `2 * 3`, which is `6`.

In case of `and` operation between multiple operands, it returns the 1<sup>st</sup> non-`True` value, and if all the values are `True`, it returns the last value.
Similarly, for `or` operator, the expression say, `A or B or C`, returns the 1<sup>st</sup> `True` value. And if all the values are `False`, it returns the last value.